# Is self variable computed multiple times if functions are called more than once in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, methods, self

I have a class where the shared variable self.a is obtained after a very heavy computation which requires a lot of time:

```
class MyClass(object):
def __init__(self):
    # ----------------------------------
    # function computationally demanding 
    out = demanding_function() # In this example, the output is a list of characters ['A','X','R','N','L']
    # ----------------------------------
    self.a = out  

def fun1(self, string):
    out = []
    for letter in self.a:
        out.append(string+letter)
    return out

def fun2(self, number):
    out = []
    for letter in self.a:
        out.append(str(number)+letter)
    return out

o = MyClass()
x = o.fun1('Hello ')
y = o.fun2(2)
```

As you can see, `self.a` is used by the functions `fun1` and `fun2`.
Here is my question is the following: if I call those 2 functions, is the `demanding_function()` executed multiple times or just once?

Note: this is a generic example and the variables don't have any specific meaning

Comment: No. Say `demanding_function()` returns 1. `out == 1`, and therefore `self.a == 1`. From now on, whenever you use its methods on the instance, it will simply use the value stored in `self.a`, which is 1. Unless your initializing an instance, the `__init__` method is never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called just once, when the class instance is initialised i.e. when the `__init__` of the class is called. Every other time you access `self.a`, the already assigned value is used; so no worries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) one more curiosity: let's pretend I create a package, where in the __init__.py file I have other functions (fun3, fun4...) which call fun1 and fun2... is the slef variable still executed once? Hopefully the question makes sense...

Comment: The self variable is an instance of the class, I'm not sure what you mean by *being executed*. If the functions are in `__init__`, then they only get called when the class is instantiated.

Comment: Sorry I meant the demanding_function() that computes the value to be stored in self...

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is only called once, when you instantiate the object.  Any subsequent method calls using that instantiated object will use the already-computed values of instance varaibles

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) one more curiosity: let's pretend I create a package, where in the __init__.py file I have other functions (fun3, fun4...) which call fun1 and fun2... is the slef variable still executed once? Hopefully the question makes sense...

Comment: @FedericoGentile yes, as long as you're not re-initiating the same instance. The `self` which is one of your parameters, isn't *really* a parameter - it's just telling the function to use initiated attributes of the instance that equals `self`.

Comment: sorry about my ignorance but what does it mean to re-initiate the same instance in practice?